# HTML Button tags are ignored

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a problem in my angular project. I have a raw text with hashtags, for example: `Listening to the rain, falling on the streets #Rain #Chill`

Now I want those 2 hashtags to be buttons, so I had this in my typescript:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.description = this.description.replace(/#(\w+)/g, '<button (click)="onHashtagClick($1)" class="hashtag">#$1</button>');
}

onHashtagClick(hashtag:string) {
    console.log(hashtag);
}
```

This results in the following description:

```
Listening to the rain, falling on the streets <button (click)="onHashtagClick(Rain)" class="hashtag">#Rain</button> <button (click)="onHashtagClick(Chill)" class="hashtag">#Chill</button>
```

But when I put it in my HTML, the element shows up like this:
[image]

The HTML tags of the button are literally printed on the screen. I found that in Angular, I needed to use the [innerHTML] tag for this, so my HTML became:

```
<label class="description" [innerHTML]="description"></label>
```

But that resulted in the original text without any HTML tags around the hashtags:
[image]

How can I make buttons of the hashtags (no hyperlinks). Please let men know what I am doing wrong?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really need buttons I would create a button array and use ngFor to show the list of buttons.

First:
Create an array of buttons

```
public buttons:Array<string> = [];
```

Second: Extract the buttons from string with regex match.

```
this.description.match(/#(\w+)/g).forEach((e) => {
    buttons.push(e);
});
```

Third: Show buttons with *ngFor

```
<button *ngFor="let i of buttons" (click)="onHashtagClick(i)">{{i}}</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

When you created a button you need to use one-way binding syntax

instead of

```
<button class="hashtag" onclick="onHashtagClick($1)">#$1</button>
```

you write your click function like this:

```
'<button class="hashtag" (click)="onHashtagClick($1)">#$1</button>
```

Also where you say 'Here is the HTML:' there is nothing there.

Comment: When I use it like you said: `this.description = this.description.replace(/#(\w+)/g, '<button class="hashtag" (click)="onHashtagClick($1)">#$1</button>');`.... The description is still a full text without any buttons

Comment: When I make an external label of it instead of a button and add the `(click)` attribute, the hashtag is surrounded by a `label` tag, but the entire `(click)` attribute is gone in the html???